# PHP check for not > 0

Tags: php, if-statement

Currently, the only way I can think of to reasonably check for this without bloated logic:

```
if ( $value > 0 ) {

    // Okay

} else {

    // Not Okay

}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Simply `if($value != 0 && $value != null) { ... } ` . So that `else` part not needed here.

Comment: If the code within is really short you can go for a ternary operator, but that doesn't change much

Comment: _Is there a better way?_ - What would be better?

Comment: Wouldn't not greater than 0 just be less than 0? `$value < 0` Unless I'm completely missing the point here.

Comment: @Ranjith OP didn't say he's not having an `else` clause

Comment: I think the only thing else you could do with that to reduce logic (or code anyway) is decide if you need to do some processing with a value that is less than or equal to 0.  If not, then chuck the `else` branch.

Comment: I guess there really is no better way (in this case), as the value itself could be a string, or null, or integer, or float value (positive, or negative). I just feel like there had to be a better way that might increase efficiency by a microsecond or two. Thanks for all of your comments!

Answer (score 3):

The logical negation of "greater than 0" is "equal or smaller  than 0".

```
if ($value <= 0) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 to counter the negative vote on a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is a normal way to resolve problem. Also you can use this:

```
$value > 0 ? echo "Okay"; : echo "Not Okay";
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways you can go about this.

```
if (!($value > 0)) {
    //If value not greater than 0
}

if ($value <= 0) {
    //If value equal to or less than 0
}
```

Or if it is a simple assignment / return you can go and use short-if.

```
//Assign to variable
$variable = $value > 0 ? 'greater' : 'equal to or less';
//Return from function
return $value > 0 ? 'greater' : 'equal to or less';
```